# How to assign a click event handler to part of a drawn rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms

Imagine I use the .NET graphic classes to draw a rectangle.

How could I then assign an event so that if the user clicks a certain point, or a certain point range, something happens (a click event handler)?

I was reading CLR via C# and the event section, and I thought of this scenario from what I had read.

A code example of this would really improve my understanding of events in C#/.NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) method translates cursor coordinates to control-relative coordinates. I.e. if you cursor is at (screenX, screenY) position on the screen it can be at (formX, formY) position relatively to form's top-left corner. We need to call it to bring cursor position into coordinate system used by our rectangle.

[Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(VS.71).aspx) method makes control to redraw itself. In our case it triggers OnPaint event handler to redraw rectangle with a new border color.

Answer (score 5):

You can assign Click event handler to control whose surface will be used to draw rectangle.
Here is a small example:
When you click on form inside of rectangle it will be drawn with red border when you click outside it will be drawn with black border.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Rectangle rect;
    private Pen pen = Pens.Black;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, Width - 30, Height - 60);
        Click += Form1_Click;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }

    void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point cursorPos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        if (rect.Contains(cursorPos)) 
        {
            pen = Pens.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            pen = Pens.Black;
        }
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```